# "One of the most dangerous roads in the world": Where is it?

Tags: safety, identify-this, off-road

A video recently seen floating about Facebook purports to show one of the "most dangerous roads in the world".  But where is this road?  Is it open to the public?

[The video](http://hitpunjab.com/dd-dfj-jf-f/), and a couple screen caps:

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Gilles: I'm not sure that Stack Exchange's strict rules on copyright allow posting such images without permission.

Comment: @hippietrail: I think this should fall under "fair use"

Comment: @Flimzy: Could be. I'm not sure whether SE goes in for "fair use" and I failed to find their official stance. I know Wikipedia does not go in for "fair use" though so you never know.

Comment: @hippietrail: Sure it does. It frequently quotes portions of copyrighted works; this falls under fair use. [Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_fish_(The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)#Babel_fish). And another [example of fair use on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanic_(1997_film)), and their [rationale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Titanic_poster.jpg).

Comment: Hmm I dunno they seem to ban a lot of things including photos with advertising in the background. Not that they seem to police all of their policies equally. Anyway I was "just sayin" d-;

Comment: @hippietrail: Photographs like that fall into other complicated legal areas, and it's no longer just about copyright at that point.

Comment: @Flimzy: Aha this might be the official Stack Exchange word on such things that I was thinking of: **[Defending Attribution Required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/)**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Having been to the Death Road in Bolivia, I can  confirm it looks quite different to this.

This video would actually appear to be in the Himalayas, believed to be between Killar and Kishtwar in northern India, above the Chenab river.

[Source](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2508046/What-ledg-ends-Spine-tingling-footage-British-passengers-creeping-worlds-deadliest-roads-wagon-teeters-brink-2-000ft-sheer-drop.html) with more pictures, and detail.

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer, here is another video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKGEtKG5HrI

Comment: Yes there's definitely dangerous roads like this other than the Bolivian "death road". Such roads are famous for ["bus plunges"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_plunge) and one of the countries with the most bus plunges, I believe, is Nepal. Also in the Himalayas.

Answer (score 3):

This video was on Canada AM on CTV this morning and the location was given as Nanga Parbut, Pakistan.

https://twitter.com/CTVCanadaAM

http://canadaam.ctvnews.ca/

[Jeff Hutcheson's Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/jeffhutcheson/status/402782498716803073) gives the details and a link to the video on Facebook. Jeff is the presenter on the show. See also [this tweet](https://twitter.com/jeffhutcheson/status/402774999234142208).

Here is [the video on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87GivARsGlI).

Comment: I followed both of those links, but don't see the video in question... ?

Comment: Check the twitter feed.

Answer (score -1):

You're almost certainly talking about Bolivia's "Death Road", also known as [Yungas Road](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yungas_Road).

Didn't mean to jump Affable Geek's answer, had the browser open without a refresh before I posted.

Comment: Having done the Death Road, I don't actually think this is it....I certainly don't remember any half tunnels? Can't watch the vid, but I'm not sure about it....

Comment: The Bolivian death road is a walk in the park compared to the road in question..